# flutter throws null exception when setting shared preferences

Tags: flutter

hello I am currently learning about streams in flutter and I came across a timer application. that involves me storing data using shared preferences. I have a thrown exception when I try to store the default preference to the phone I traced it back to this code block:

```
  readSettings() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int workTime = prefs.getInt(WORKTIME);
    if (workTime == null) {
      await prefs.setInt(WORKTIME, int.parse('30'));
    }
    int shortBreak = prefs.getInt(SHORTBREAK);
    if (shortBreak == null) {
      await prefs.setInt(SHORTBREAK, int.parse('5'));
    }
    int longBreak = prefs.getInt(LONGBREAK);
    if (longBreak == null) {
      await prefs.setInt(LONGBREAK, int.parse('20'));
    }
    setState(() {
      txtWork.text = workTime.toString();
      txtShort.text = shortBreak.toString();
      txtLong.text = longBreak.toString();
    });
  }
```

this is the error I recieve:

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'text=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: text="30")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that most likely your error is not caused by SharedPreferences.

Also assuming that `txtWork.text` is a textEditingController.
Go up to where you defined `TextEditingController textWork;`

and change them to this:

`TextEditingController textWork = TextEditingController ();`

`TextEditingController txtLong = TextEditingController ();`

`TextEditingController txtShort = TextEditingController ();`

It should work, please update on what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think that txtWork the object that have .text is null
so you are trying to do this:

null.text = "30"

Check where you instantiate it.

Comment: thank you for the hint to check for the help with checking where I instantiate I did in the intstate function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by moving my textEditing controllers out of my intiState function

old code:

```
void initState() {
  TextEditingController txtWork = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtShort = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtLong = TextEditingController();

    readSettings();
    super.initState();
  }
```

new code:

```
  TextEditingController txtWork = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtShort = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtLong = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    readSettings();
    super.initState();
  }
```